# Compile OpenSceneGraph 3.0.1 with VS 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, openscenegraph

I'm trying to compile OpenSceneGraph 3.0.1 with VisualStudio 2010 but during the compilation I get the following errors

```
Error   50  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _jpeg_CreateCompress referenced in function "private: enum osgDB::ReaderWriter::WriteResult::WriteStatus __thiscall ReaderWriterJPEG::write_JPEG_file(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class osg::Image const &,int)const " (?write_JPEG_file@ReaderWriterJPEG@@ABE?AW4WriteStatus@WriteResult@ReaderWriter@osgDB@@AAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@ABVImage@osg@@H@Z)  F:\library\OpenSceneGraph-3.0.1\built\src\osgPlugins\jpeg\ReaderWriterJPEG.obj  Plugins jpeg
Error   41  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _jpeg_CreateDecompress referenced in function "unsigned char * __cdecl osgDBJPEG::simage_jpeg_load(class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,int *,int *,int *)" (?simage_jpeg_load@osgDBJPEG@@YAPAEAAV?$basic_istream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@PAH11@Z)    F:\library\OpenSceneGraph-3.0.1\built\src\osgPlugins\jpeg\ReaderWriterJPEG.obj  Plugins jpeg
Error   44  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _jpeg_destroy_compress referenced in function "private: enum osgDB::ReaderWriter::WriteResult::WriteStatus __thiscall ReaderWriterJPEG::write_JPEG_file(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class osg::Image const &,int)const " (?write_JPEG_file@ReaderWriterJPEG@@ABE?AW4WriteStatus@WriteResult@ReaderWriter@osgDB@@AAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@ABVImage@osg@@H@Z)    F:\library\OpenSceneGraph-3.0.1\built\src\osgPlugins\jpeg\ReaderWriterJPEG.obj  Plugins jpeg
Error   42  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _jpeg_destroy_decompress referenced in function "unsigned char * __cdecl osgDBJPEG::simage_jpeg_load(class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,int *,int *,int *)" (?simage_jpeg_load@osgDBJPEG@@YAPAEAAV?$basic_istream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@PAH11@Z)  F:\library\OpenSceneGraph-3.0.1\built\src\osgPlugins\jpeg\ReaderWriterJPEG.obj  Plugins jpeg
Error   45  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _jpeg_finish_compress referenced in function "private: enum osgDB::ReaderWriter::WriteResult::WriteStatus __thiscall ReaderWriterJPEG::write_JPEG_file(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class osg::Image const &,int)const " (?write_JPEG_file@ReaderWriterJPEG@@ABE?AW4WriteStatus@WriteResult@ReaderWriter@osgDB@@AAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@ABVImage@osg@@H@Z) F:\library\OpenSceneGraph-3.0.1\built\src\osgPlugins\jpeg\ReaderWriterJPEG.obj  Plugins jpeg
Error   37  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _jpeg_finish_decompress referenced in function "unsigned char * __cdecl osgDBJPEG::simage_jpeg_load(class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,int *,int *,int *)" (?simage_jpeg_load@osgDBJPEG@@YAPAEAAV?$basic_istream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@PAH11@Z)   F:\library\OpenSceneGraph-3.0.1\built\src\osgPlugins\jpeg\ReaderWriterJPEG.obj  Plugins jpeg
Error   40  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _jpeg_read_header referenced in function "unsigned char * __cdecl osgDBJPEG::simage_jpeg_load(class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,int *,int *,int *)" (?simage_jpeg_load@osgDBJPEG@@YAPAEAAV?$basic_istream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@PAH11@Z) F:\library\OpenSceneGraph-3.0.1\built\src\osgPlugins\jpeg\ReaderWriterJPEG.obj  Plugins jpeg
Error   38  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _jpeg_read_scanlines referenced in function "unsigned char * __cdecl osgDBJPEG::simage_jpeg_load(class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,int *,int *,int *)" (?simage_jpeg_load@osgDBJPEG@@YAPAEAAV?$basic_istream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@PAH11@Z)  F:\library\OpenSceneGraph-3.0.1\built\src\osgPlugins\jpeg\ReaderWriterJPEG.obj  Plugins jpeg
Error   36  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _jpeg_resync_to_restart referenced in function "void __cdecl osgDBJPEG::jpeg_istream_src(struct jpeg_decompress_struct *,class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > *)" (?jpeg_istream_src@osgDBJPEG@@YAXPAUjpeg_decompress_struct@@PAV?$basic_istream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@@Z)    F:\library\OpenSceneGraph-3.0.1\built\src\osgPlugins\jpeg\ReaderWriterJPEG.obj  Plugins jpeg
Error   49  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _jpeg_set_defaults referenced in function "private: enum osgDB::ReaderWriter::WriteResult::WriteStatus __thiscall ReaderWriterJPEG::write_JPEG_file(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class osg::Image const &,int)const " (?write_JPEG_file@ReaderWriterJPEG@@ABE?AW4WriteStatus@WriteResult@ReaderWriter@osgDB@@AAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@ABVImage@osg@@H@Z)    F:\library\OpenSceneGraph-3.0.1\built\src\osgPlugins\jpeg\ReaderWriterJPEG.obj  Plugins jpeg
Error   48  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _jpeg_set_quality referenced in function "private: enum osgDB::ReaderWriter::WriteResult::WriteStatus __thiscall ReaderWriterJPEG::write_JPEG_file(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class osg::Image const &,int)const " (?write_JPEG_file@ReaderWriterJPEG@@ABE?AW4WriteStatus@WriteResult@ReaderWriter@osgDB@@AAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@ABVImage@osg@@H@Z) F:\library\OpenSceneGraph-3.0.1\built\src\osgPlugins\jpeg\ReaderWriterJPEG.obj  Plugins jpeg
Error   47  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _jpeg_start_compress referenced in function "private: enum osgDB::ReaderWriter::WriteResult::WriteStatus __thiscall ReaderWriterJPEG::write_JPEG_file(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class osg::Image const &,int)const " (?write_JPEG_file@ReaderWriterJPEG@@ABE?AW4WriteStatus@WriteResult@ReaderWriter@osgDB@@AAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@ABVImage@osg@@H@Z)  F:\library\OpenSceneGraph-3.0.1\built\src\osgPlugins\jpeg\ReaderWriterJPEG.obj  Plugins jpeg
Error   39  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _jpeg_start_decompress referenced in function "unsigned char * __cdecl osgDBJPEG::simage_jpeg_load(class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,int *,int *,int *)" (?simage_jpeg_load@osgDBJPEG@@YAPAEAAV?$basic_istream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@PAH11@Z)    F:\library\OpenSceneGraph-3.0.1\built\src\osgPlugins\jpeg\ReaderWriterJPEG.obj  Plugins jpeg
Error   43  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _jpeg_std_error referenced in function "unsigned char * __cdecl osgDBJPEG::simage_jpeg_load(class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,int *,int *,int *)" (?simage_jpeg_load@osgDBJPEG@@YAPAEAAV?$basic_istream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@PAH11@Z)   F:\library\OpenSceneGraph-3.0.1\built\src\osgPlugins\jpeg\ReaderWriterJPEG.obj  Plugins jpeg
Error   46  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _jpeg_write_scanlines referenced in function "private: enum osgDB::ReaderWriter::WriteResult::WriteStatus __thiscall ReaderWriterJPEG::write_JPEG_file(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class osg::Image const &,int)const " (?write_JPEG_file@ReaderWriterJPEG@@ABE?AW4WriteStatus@WriteResult@ReaderWriter@osgDB@@AAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@ABVImage@osg@@H@Z) F:\library\OpenSceneGraph-3.0.1\built\src\osgPlugins\jpeg\ReaderWriterJPEG.obj  Plugins jpeg
Error   22  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _png_create_info_struct referenced in function "public: class osgDB::ReaderWriter::ReadResult __thiscall ReaderWriterPNG::readPNGStream(class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &)const " (?readPNGStream@ReaderWriterPNG@@QBE?AVReadResult@ReaderWriter@osgDB@@AAV?$basic_istream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@@Z) F:\library\OpenSceneGraph-3.0.1\built\src\osgPlugins\png\ReaderWriterPNG.obj    Plugins png
Error   25  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _png_create_read_struct referenced in function "public: class osgDB::ReaderWriter::ReadResult __thiscall ReaderWriterPNG::readPNGStream(class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &)const " (?readPNGStream@ReaderWriterPNG@@QBE?AVReadResult@ReaderWriter@osgDB@@AAV?$basic_istream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@@Z) F:\library\OpenSceneGraph-3.0.1\built\src\osgPlugins\png\ReaderWriterPNG.obj    Plugins png
Error   34  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _png_create_write_struct referenced in function "public: enum osgDB::ReaderWriter::WriteResult::WriteStatus __thiscall ReaderWriterPNG::writePngStream(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class osg::Image const &,int)const " (?writePngStream@ReaderWriterPNG@@QBE?AW4WriteStatus@WriteResult@ReaderWriter@osgDB@@AAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@ABVImage@osg@@H@Z)   F:\library\OpenSceneGraph-3.0.1\built\src\osgPlugins\png\ReaderWriterPNG.obj    Plugins png
Error   19  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _png_destroy_read_struct referenced in function "public: class osgDB::ReaderWriter::ReadResult __thiscall ReaderWriterPNG::readPNGStream(class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &)const " (?readPNGStream@ReaderWriterPNG@@QBE?AVReadResult@ReaderWriter@osgDB@@AAV?$basic_istream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@@Z)    F:\library\OpenSceneGraph-3.0.1\built\src\osgPlugins\png\ReaderWriterPNG.obj    Plugins png
Error   26  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _png_destroy_write_struct referenced in function "public: enum osgDB::ReaderWriter::WriteResult::WriteStatus __thiscall ReaderWriterPNG::writePngStream(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class osg::Image const &,int)const " (?writePngStream@ReaderWriterPNG@@QBE?AW4WriteStatus@WriteResult@ReaderWriter@osgDB@@AAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@ABVImage@osg@@H@Z)  F:\library\OpenSceneGraph-3.0.1\built\src\osgPlugins\png\ReaderWriterPNG.obj    Plugins png
Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _png_get_channels referenced in function "public: class osgDB::ReaderWriter::ReadResult __thiscall ReaderWriterPNG::readPNGStream(class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &)const " (?readPNGStream@ReaderWriterPNG@@QBE?AVReadResult@ReaderWriter@osgDB@@AAV?$basic_istream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@@Z)   F:\library\OpenSceneGraph-3.0.1\built\src\osgPlugins\png\ReaderWriterPNG.obj    Plugins png
Error   24  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _png_get_error_ptr referenced in function "public: class osgDB::ReaderWriter::ReadResult __thiscall ReaderWriterPNG::readPNGStream(class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &)const " (?readPNGStream@ReaderWriterPNG@@QBE?AVReadResult@ReaderWriter@osgDB@@AAV?$basic_istream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@@Z)  F:\library\OpenSceneGraph-3.0.1\built\src\osgPlugins\png\ReaderWriterPNG.obj    Plugins png
Error   8   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _png_get_gAMA referenced in function "public: class osgDB::ReaderWriter::ReadResult __thiscall ReaderWriterPNG::readPNGStream(class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &)const " (?readPNGStream@ReaderWriterPNG@@QBE?AVReadResult@ReaderWriter@osgDB@@AAV?$basic_istream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@@Z)   F:\library\OpenSceneGraph-3.0.1\built\src\osgPlugins\png\ReaderWriterPNG.obj    Plugins png
Error   16  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _png_get_IHDR referenced in function "public: class osgDB::ReaderWriter::ReadResult __thiscall ReaderWriterPNG::readPNGStream(class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &)const " (?readPNGStream@ReaderWriterPNG@@QBE?AVReadResult@ReaderWriter@osgDB@@AAV?$basic_istream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@@Z)   F:\library\OpenSceneGraph-3.0.1\built\src\osgPlugins\png\ReaderWriterPNG.obj    Plugins png
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _png_get_io_ptr referenced in function "void __cdecl png_read_istream(struct png_struct_def *,unsigned char *,unsigned int)" (?png_read_istream@@YAXPAUpng_struct_def@@PAEI@Z)    F:\library\OpenSceneGraph-3.0.1\built\src\osgPlugins\png\ReaderWriterPNG.obj    Plugins png
Error   5   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _png_get_rowbytes referenced in function "public: class osgDB::ReaderWriter::ReadResult __thiscall ReaderWriterPNG::readPNGStream(class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &)const " (?readPNGStream@ReaderWriterPNG@@QBE?AVReadResult@ReaderWriter@osgDB@@AAV?$basic_istream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@@Z)   F:\library\OpenSceneGraph-3.0.1\built\src\osgPlugins\png\ReaderWriterPNG.obj    Plugins png
Error   11  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _png_get_valid referenced in function "public: class osgDB::ReaderWriter::ReadResult __thiscall ReaderWriterPNG::readPNGStream(class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &)const " (?readPNGStream@ReaderWriterPNG@@QBE?AVReadResult@ReaderWriter@osgDB@@AAV?$basic_istream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@@Z)  F:\library\OpenSceneGraph-3.0.1\built\src\osgPlugins\png\ReaderWriterPNG.obj    Plugins png
Error   3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _png_read_end referenced in function "public: class osgDB::ReaderWriter::ReadResult __thiscall ReaderWriterPNG::readPNGStream(class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &)const " (?readPNGStream@ReaderWriterPNG@@QBE?AVReadResult@ReaderWriter@osgDB@@AAV?$basic_istream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@@Z)   F:\library\OpenSceneGraph-3.0.1\built\src\osgPlugins\png\ReaderWriterPNG.obj    Plugins png
Error   4   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _png_read_image referenced in function "public: class osgDB::ReaderWriter::ReadResult __thiscall ReaderWriterPNG::readPNGStream(class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &)const " (?readPNGStream@ReaderWriterPNG@@QBE?AVReadResult@ReaderWriter@osgDB@@AAV?$basic_istream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@@Z) F:\library\OpenSceneGraph-3.0.1\built\src\osgPlugins\png\ReaderWriterPNG.obj    Plugins png
Error   17  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _png_read_info referenced in function "public: class osgDB::ReaderWriter::ReadResult __thiscall ReaderWriterPNG::readPNGStream(class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &)const " (?readPNGStream@ReaderWriterPNG@@QBE?AVReadResult@ReaderWriter@osgDB@@AAV?$basic_istream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@@Z)  F:\library\OpenSceneGraph-3.0.1\built\src\osgPlugins\png\ReaderWriterPNG.obj    Plugins png
Error   6   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _png_read_update_info referenced in function "public: class osgDB::ReaderWriter::ReadResult __thiscall ReaderWriterPNG::readPNGStream(class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &)const " (?readPNGStream@ReaderWriterPNG@@QBE?AVReadResult@ReaderWriter@osgDB@@AAV?$basic_istream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@@Z)   F:\library\OpenSceneGraph-3.0.1\built\src\osgPlugins\png\ReaderWriterPNG.obj    Plugins png
Error   31  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _png_set_bgr referenced in function "public: enum osgDB::ReaderWriter::WriteResult::WriteStatus __thiscall ReaderWriterPNG::writePngStream(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class osg::Image const &,int)const " (?writePngStream@ReaderWriterPNG@@QBE?AW4WriteStatus@WriteResult@ReaderWriter@osgDB@@AAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@ABVImage@osg@@H@Z)   F:\library\OpenSceneGraph-3.0.1\built\src\osgPlugins\png\ReaderWriterPNG.obj    Plugins png
Error   32  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _png_set_compression_level referenced in function "public: enum osgDB::ReaderWriter::WriteResult::WriteStatus __thiscall ReaderWriterPNG::writePngStream(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class osg::Image const &,int)const " (?writePngStream@ReaderWriterPNG@@QBE?AW4WriteStatus@WriteResult@ReaderWriter@osgDB@@AAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@ABVImage@osg@@H@Z) F:\library\OpenSceneGraph-3.0.1\built\src\osgPlugins\png\ReaderWriterPNG.obj    Plugins png
Error   23  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _png_set_error_fn referenced in function "public: class osgDB::ReaderWriter::ReadResult __thiscall ReaderWriterPNG::readPNGStream(class std::basic_istream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &)const " (?readPNGStream@ReaderWriterPNG@@QBE?AVReadResult@ReaderWriter@osgDB@@AAV?$basic_istream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@@Z)   F:\library\OpenSceneGraph-3.0.1\built\src\osgPlugins\png\ReaderWriterPNG.obj    Plugins png
```

Please advise.

Comment: It looks like you're missing libjpeg and libpng.

Comment: Does libjpeg and libpng part of OSG or they are seperate libraries ? But OSG 3.2.1 compiles correct without errors ...

Comment: http://www.openscenegraph.org/index.php/download-section/dependencies

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I see the dependencies

Comment: Did you solve this with @RetiredNinja's advice? If so, tell him/her to post an answer and accept it.